# How to receive POST data in python when using XMLHttpRequest() and Apache on Ubuntu? Not using flask

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I have really a hard time getting data from a client side javascript, using xmlHTTPrequest POST to a very simple python3 cgi-bin program. I see numerous examples with Forms and Flask, but I really want to stay as simple as possible - an NO, I cannot use a Form as I want to react on a mouse-click on a graph - which creates an 'onClick' event which I catch; AND on the server side I use Apache2 as webserver, not the python provided webserver. What I have is:

**Client side:**

```
data.time=3600;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //set the py file you want to send data to --> 
  xhr.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/load.py", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  ....  (here is the onreadystatechange-function - which is not important here) .....

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data);
```

**On the server side:  file load.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi, cgitb
import sys

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print(" ")
print("Form=",form)
```

And this results in an internal server error  (500), with the following error in the Apache2 error.log:

```
 File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/load.py", line 8, in <module>
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/cgi.py", line 485, in __init__
    self.read_single()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/cgi.py", line 678, in read_single
    self.read_binary()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/cgi.py", line 700, in read_binary
    self.file.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I seem to understand that the TypeError is internal to the cgi code? So what should I do about this? When I run the load.py file stand-alone (python3 load.py) everything is fine? Unfortunately I do not find any examples of using a POST to a python server side without forms....(on the client side).

Comment: Looks like this is indeed an error in cgi: https://github.com/webpy/webpy/issues/574 which has not ben solved I guess..

Answer (score 0):

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

You have chosen to base your new solution
on old technology that is going away.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html

> Deprecated since version 3.11, will be removed in version 3.13: The cgi module is deprecated (see PEP 594 for details and alternatives).
>
> The FieldStorage class can typically be replaced with ... the email.message module or [multipart](https://pypi.org/project/multipart) for POST

https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi

> CGI is deemed as inefficient because every incoming request is handled in a new process. PEP 206 considers the module as:
>
> “[…] designed poorly and are now near-impossible to fix (cgi) […]”

Recommend you re-evaluate your approach to producing a supportable solution.
The links offer helpful resources for this FAQ.

Comment: Dear J_H would you care for posting a simple example how multipart replaces cgi.FieldStorage --- I do not see any description and info on how to use Multipart on the provided links...

Comment: https://github.com/defnull/multipart/blob/13af8ab/test/test_multipart.py#L247 explains how to invoke `.parse_form_data()`. It would be helpful if you were to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a failing ("red") unit test to your original question which describes some particular form data of interest. Typically this simply isn't an issue, as `Flask` just deals with it, but I suppose a few use cases exist which will absolutely prohibit importing a [flask](https://pypi.org/project/Flask) dependency.

Comment: Dear J_H I really only want to send a JSON string of data to my python application, kind of in the following form: {"temp" : 35.5, "hum" : 78 , "mode" : "auto"} Where this JSON string can be of varying length. The ONLY thing I want it is that the sting arrives in its entirety in my python application.  In my case, the variable "form" should be the exact appearance of what I send as "data" from my JS.